# Is 'an arbitrary $x$' equivalent to 'for all $x$' in the proof of the distributive law for the algebra of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading elements of set theory by Enderton. I have no formal training in set theory or mathematical logic, so please bear with me when it comes to poor formatting or simple errors.

The proof is to show that

$$A\cap (B\cup C) = (A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)$$

Also let $P$ equal the left hand side of the equation and $Q$ equal the right hand side.

The book states that if we are to consider an arbitrary x, and that we do not know if $x \in A, x\in B,x\in C$. There are 8 possible combinations for $x$ being in $A, B$, or $C$ or not being in $A, B$, or $C$. It can be shown for all eight combinations that $$x\in P\iff x\in Q \quad (1)$$

My confusion comes now when the axiom of extensionality is invoked to then say that $P=Q$.

I understand that this may well be a trivial point, but When the book says 'an arbitrary $x$', that implies one object x that is a set. So following the statement we arrived at was$$x\in P\iff x\in Q $$

However, extensionality in its full form is $$\forall A \forall B[\forall x(x\in A \iff x\in B) \implies A=B]$$

I understand P and Q are defined sets here, so maybe it can be reduced to $$\forall x(x\in A \iff x\in B) \implies A=B \quad (2)$$

My concern here is that equation (1) and equation (2) are different statements. (1) is about 'an arbitrary $x$', whereas (2) is about all objects $x$. To invoke extionsonality then is it the case that in mathematics when 'an arbitrary object' is discussed, is it equivalent to discussing all objects of that type? I am sorry if this is pedantic and trivial, but I am having a hard time understanding why they are equivalent. Or more specifically, why extentionality can be invoked on equation (1)?

Comment: Arbitrary=not assuming anything(apart from what was told beforehand)|For all=for every element(from a class given beforehand), if you proved something for *arbitrary* element from $A$ then *for all* elements in $A$ the same proof works

Comment: Incidentally, the MathJax for set inclusion is `\in`, not `\epsilon`.  Definite A for effort, though.

Comment: if u take *any* object or an *arbitrary* object of some kind and show something, then u showed that something *for all* objects of that kind, since u made no additional assumptions on that *arbitrary* object except being of that certain kind. *for any*, *for all*, *for an arbitrary* are synonyms in this sense.

Comment: Thank you guys, that makes... sense. I don't know why I didn't think of it that way. Thank you for the tip as well Brian!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe another example proof will help illustrate why we say "an arbitrary x".

Proof: Let $f:X \to Y$ be a function and let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $X$.  Given $A \subset B$, we need to show $f(A) \subset f(B)$ [we really aim to show for every $f(a) \in f(A)$ that $f(a) \in f(B)$].  Let $y$ be an arbitrary element in $f(A)$ .  Since $y\in f(A)$ there exists an $x\in A$ such that $f(x)=y$, because $A \subset B$ then $x \in B$ this implies that $f(x) \in f(B)$ which shows that $y \in f(B)$.  $\square$  $$$$Since we chose an arbitrary and not specific element in the set $f(A)$ this means that this argument works for any element in $f(A)$.

On the other hand say we wanted to do a proof by contradiction.

Proof:  Let $f:X \to Y$ be a function and let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $X$ with $A \subset B$.  Assume to the contrary that $f(A) \not\subset f(B)$, then $\exists$ $y \in f(A)$ such that $y \notin f(B)$.  Since $y \in f(A)$ then $\exists$ $x \in A$ such that $f(x)=y$.  Using the fact that $A \subset B$ $\implies$ $x \in B$ $\implies$ $f(x) \in f(B)$ $\implies$ $y \in f(B)$ a contradiction. #

Notice how in the proof by contradiction we did not choose an arbitrary element.  We said there exists at least one element meaning there could be more, but there is at least one.  In other words we are saying we can find at least one specific element $y$ ,in this case, in $f(A)$ that is not in $f(B)$.  We did not chose an arbitrary element because we do not need to show this to be true for every element in $f(A)$ just that an element exists to refute the claim $f(A) \subset f(B)$.